# Is there any way to run spark scripts and store outputs in parallel with oozie?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, oozie

I have 3 spark scripts and every one of them has 1 spark sql to read a partitioned table and store to some hdfs location. Every script has a different sql statement and different folder location to store data into.

```
test1.py - Read from table 1 and store to location 1.
test2.py - Read from table 2 and store to location 2.
test3.py - Read from table 3 and store to location 3.
```

I run these scripts using fork action in oozie and all three run. But the problem is that the scripts are not storing data in parallel. 
Once the store from one script is done then the other store starts.

My expectation is to store all 3 tables data into their respective locations parallely.

I have tried FAIR scheduling and other scheduler techniques in the sparks scripts but those don't work. Can anyone please help.I am stuck with  it from last 2 days.

I am using AWS EMR 5.15, Spark 2.4 and Oozie 5.0.0.

Comment: three separate hue workflow spark actions will do this.. u can create a workflow with 3 actions each running its own script parallely. success of all actions is success of workflow.

Comment: How are you triggering the scripts currently?

Comment: for shell script use shell action... trigger spark submit command from shell script

Comment: @jayadeep jayaraman ...Current execution is :- I have a wokflow.xml file with a fork action which runs 3 different spark actions and then the control goes to the joining action. Every spark action out of the 3 has one of the 3 scripts. Every script has a spark.sql(select *) from the same table and store into a location which is different for every script.

Comment: @user2526641 can you please give me a small example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**For Capacity scheduler**

If you are submitting job to a single queue whichever job come first in the queue gets the resources. intra-queue preemption won't work.

I can see a related Jira for Intraqueue preemption in Capacity scheduler. https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/YARN-10073

You can read more https://blog.cloudera.com/yarn-capacity-scheduler/

**For Fair scheduler**

Setting the "yarn.scheduler.fair.preemption" parameter to "true" in yarn-site.xml enables preemption at the cluster level. By default this is false i.e no preemption.

**Your problem could be:**

1 job is taking maximum resources. To verify this please check Yarn UI and Spark UI.

Or if you have more than 1 yarn queue (other than default). Try setting *User Limit Factor* > 1 for the queue you are using.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. Actually the problem was the lack of resources for 3 parallel jobs. I have tuned the spark memory settings to make it work.